# Which column stores ASPX page body?

Tags: site-column, aspx

I understand that a body of ASPX page published on site is stored in a dedicated column. What is exact name of this column? Some authors mention "PublishingPageContent", others "WikiField". Does it depend on library type? How to determine exact field in client side code? Thank you.

Comment: It depends on the page type being used, if it's a Publishing Page, the field name is "PublishingPageContent". If it's a Wiki page, the field name is "WikiField". [Read More](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-wiki-publishing-web-part-pages-overview)

Comment: @Arsalan Adam Khatri, Thank you very much for your comment. I suppose it answers my questions.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer than :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the page type being used, if it's a Publishing Page, the field name is "PublishingPageContent". If it's a Wiki page, the field name is "WikiField".

[SharePoint Wiki, Publishing and Web Part Pages](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-wiki-publishing-web-part-pages-overview)

**UPDATE**

> In case its a modern page in SharePoint Online, it will be "CanvasContent1"

Thanks to [Gautam Sheth](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/8068/gautam-sheth) for mentioning this in comments

Comment: in case its a modern page in SharePoint Online, it will be `CanvasContent1`

Comment: @Gautam Sheth, Your valuable addition for SharePoint Online was especially useful for me to have a complete set of alternatives. Thank you.